# Spring RabbitMQ. Determine all consumers when multiple app instances are connected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-rabbit

I have an application that creates/stops/resumes queues and consumers on a runtime. And there're multiple instances of that application. And what problem I faced is that the instance knows about the consumers created only by itself. So if there're two queues, each have one consumer created by a different app instance, then `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.getQueueNames` returns only one queue that this instance is listening

Example behaviour:

- create queueA from app instance1
- create queueB from app instance2
- get all queues that are currently listening from an instance1 - gives only queueA

What I need: get all listeners from any app instance and remove any queue listener from any app instance.

I've played a lot with a connection factories, and have no luck.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing available using the AMQP protocol or the Spring library; RabbitMQ does provide a REST API and a Java client binding (Hop) which might help, but you would need to communicate somehow with each instance to shut down the listeners.